# How to match autocmd pattern for unique file

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, manpages

I'm trying to make autocommands that will run only when the buffer is a man page (`:Man`), but I can't get the right pattern as I'm not too familiar with regex and globs. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
autocmd! BufEnter *man://* call Myfunc()
autocmd! BufEnter [^man://]* call Myfunc()
```

but nothing seems to work. Any alternative ideas are okay too.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to use a `FileType` buffer. The problem with `BufEnter` is that the buffer may not yet be fully set up when it's run; I also don't think it's run for new buffers.

I'm also not entirely sure if I follow where you go the `man://` pattern from? I don't see that in the source? And using `bufname('')` gives me `/home/martin/ls.~`, not `man://...`?

At any rate, something like this should work as you expect:

```
autocmd! FileType man call Myfunc()
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I have tested this works:

```
function! Test()
    echom "entering man buffer " . expand('%')
endfunction

autocmd! BufEnter man://* call Test()
```

Comment: odd.. I tried it in vim8.1 and nvim0.3 by `vim --noplugin -u test.vim` but It  seems not working.. any idea?

Comment: It only works when I open the man page manually through `new man://test(1)` but not using the `:Man test` command.

Comment: Actually it there is something weird: when I do my firt `:Man ls` the autocommand doesn't work but if I use `:Man`  again it works. I would say that maybe `:Man` sets the filename after the `BufEnter` event is triggered. Depending on what you want to do maybe you can use another autocommand event.